# Pulling Results From Query into data table

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

I am having trouble pulling information from the query and putting it into the dataTable.

I need to pull up book entries that are greater than the entered price.

I have that part somewhat working I think, but I need to sort it into the datatable so it can be read. (make it look pretty)

I don't understand where I am missing code?? In the query to sort it out more?? or can I just access the info and thro it into the dataTable.

Here is what my BookQueries.xhtml page looks like, but its not working! :(

```
    <h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{bookController.findBookGreater()}" var="item"
                 border="1">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Book Query Results" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Books" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Price" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book.price}" />
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

In the BookController.java class I have:

```
 public List<Book> findBookGreater() {
    return ejbFacade.findBookByPrice(bookPrice);
}
```

And in the BookFacade.java I have:

```
    public List<Book> findBookByPrice(Integer bprice) {

EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findBooksGreater");
query.setParameter("bookprice", bprice);
List resultList = query.getResultList();
return resultList;

}
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP THAT CAN BE OFFERED!!

Answer (score 1):

You define `var="item"`

```
<h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{bookController.findBookGreater()}" var="item"
             border="1">
```

So each element of the list will be refered as  `item`, but you try to refer to `book`

```
<h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />
```

Use instead

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.title}" />
```